# Pandas dataframe "all true" criterion

Tags: python, pandas

Python 2.7, Pandas 0.18.

I have a DataFrame, and I have methods that select a subset of the rows via a criterion parameter. I'd like to know a more idiomatic way to write a criterion that matches all rows.

Here's a very simple example:

```
import pandas as pd

def apply_to_matching(df,criterion):
   df.loc[criterion,'A'] = df[criterion]['A']*df[criterion]['B']

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4],'B':[10,100,1000,10000]})

criterion = (df['A']<3)
result = apply_to_matching(df,criterion)
print df
```

The output would be:

```
     A      B
0   10     10
1  200    100
2    3   1000
3    4  10000
```

because the criterion applies to only the first two rows.

I would like to know the idiomatic way to create a criterion that selects all rows of the DataFrame.

This could be done by adding a column of all true values to the DataFrame:

```
# Add a column
df['AllTrue']=True
criterion = df['AllTrue']
result = apply_to_matching(df,criterion)
print df.drop('AllTrue',axis=1)
```

The output is:

```
       A      B
0     10     10
1    200    100
2   3000   1000
3  40000  10000
```

but that approach adds a column to my DataFrame, which I have to filter out later to not get it in my output.

So, is there a more idiomatic way to do this in Pandas? One which does not require me to know anything about the column names, and not change the DataFrame?

Comment: It's not really clear from your question what you're trying to do. Might want to add some sample data and desired output, or at least clarify the goal you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When everything should be True, the boolean indexing way would require a series of `True`. With the code you have above, another way to look at it is that the `criterion` argument can also receive slices. Getting all the rows would mean slicing the entire rows like this `df.loc[:, 'A']`. As you need to pass it as an argument to `apply_to_matching` function, use `slice` builtin:

```
apply_to_matching(df, slice(None, None))
```

Comment: My only problem with this is that it can't be used with other criteria use '&': `criterion = slice(None,None); criterion2 = df['A']>2; criterion3=criterion & ceriterion2` doesn't work.

Comment: You don't need to Boolean & these two criteria as the slice is a vector of True values, why cant you just pass along criterion2 is that case?

Comment: Because if I'm passed criterion into a routine, I don't want to check if it is a slice or a criterion when I do `criterion3=criterion&criterion2`. Basically, I want to pass the criterion into a routine and treat it like any other criterion, so that the code *doesn't need to know* that criterion is "all true."

Comment: That's pity you "don't want to know" and you mention "you want polymorphism" altogether, as they are mathematically incompatible. Why would you deny to apply ad-hoc polymorphism in your function and do ` isinstance(criterion, slice)` to identify it is a question that leads to the overall design of your goal here. If you don't want to do that, then generate a dummy all true vector `dummy_all_true_criterion =  np.ones(df.shape[0])` and you pay by space and size what you don't want to pay by code and CPU

Comment: No, polymorphism means I don't have to check types in my code. If I pass the slice to a routine, I can't construct `criterion&criterion2` because `criterion` is the wrong type inside my routine, so I'd have to check the type of the argument, which **violates polymorphism.**

Comment: I don't need a course on polymorphism here, if you know one form of it that supersede functions upfront and not do triage downstream as I mention then do write your superseded function you're a fan of and still apply polymorphism to solve your issue. You didn't ask for criteria combination in your OP in the first place so also do learn how to ask the questions you want answers too. You want to combine them do `df['A']==df['A']` as a alltrue criterion. Good luck

Comment: Hey, you were lecturing me, no reason to get snippy.